# how to show table on page when it is empty in angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using angular material table component, my question is when the datasoruce is empty, we can't see the table on the web page.

[image]

but when the datasource is filled with too many data elements, it will look like

[image]

how can I still show the table when it is empty and make the table with fixed height when the data is overflowed. as shown below

[image: when]

Answer (score 0):

You can add the blank data to the data source by default and when their is no value in the table to be displayed it will display blank values that are set